# Recommendation to fix SSLv3 server responded with higher version number (TLSv1.2) than requested by client (NOT ok)

Tags: tls, openssl

I'm looking for a recommendation or more details on how to fix the issue (SSLv3 - server responded with higher version number (TLSv1.2) than requested by client (NOT ok)) reported by `testssl.sh`.

> testssl version

```
└─▪ bash testssl.sh --version

###########################################################
    testssl.sh       3.0.1 from https://testssl.sh/
```

> openssl version

```
Using "OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012" [~115 ciphers]
```

> cmd

```
└─▪ bash testssl.sh --protocols --severity LOW --hints --json xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443

[
         {
              "id"           : "SSLv3",
              "ip"           : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
              "port"         : "443",
              "severity"     : "CRITICAL",
              "finding"      : "server responded with higher version number (TLSv1.2) than requested by client"
          }
,         {
              "id"           : "TLS1",
              "ip"           : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
              "port"         : "443",
              "severity"     : "CRITICAL",
              "finding"      : "server responded with higher version number (TLSv1.2) than requested by client"
          }
]
```

The severity of the issue is **CRITICAL** for **SSLv3 & TLS1** and there is not much information about this anywhere in the `testssl.sh` codebase or issues.

Below are the details from the openssl connect and the nmap ssl-enum-ciphers:

```
└─▪ openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140468454483616:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:340:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1587765998
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

└─▪ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

No ciphers related to SSLv3 or TLS1 are shown by the nmap.
```

Is disabling SSLv3 & TLS1 will solve the problem? Or his any other way to fix this issue?

> Update

Running openssl s_client with -debug:

```
└─▪ openssl s_client -ssl3 -debug -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x16e0370 [0x16ea3b3] (128 bytes => 128 (0x80))
0000 - 16 03 00 00 7b 01 00 00-77 03 00 5e a4 78 e8 c7   ....{...w..^.x..
0010 - ca 64 0b 1c 7d 51 e6 26-a2 d8 82 3f 54 b2 23 83   .d..}Q.&...?T.#.
0020 - 9e 6f 33 4c e1 c2 6f 10-74 02 15 00 00 50 c0 14   .o3L..o.t....P..
0030 - c0 0a 00 39 00 38 00 88-00 87 c0 0f c0 05 00 35   ...9.8.........5
0040 - 00 84 c0 12 c0 08 00 16-00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a   ................
0050 - c0 13 c0 09 00 33 00 32-00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44   .....3.2.....E.D
0060 - c0 0e c0 04 00 2f 00 96-00 41 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c   ...../...A......
0070 - c0 02 00 05 00 04 00 15-00 12 00 09 00 ff 01      ...............
0080 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x16e0370 [0x16e5e63] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 51                                    ....Q
write to 0x16e0370 [0x16ef880] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                              ......(
140069848430240:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:340:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1587837160
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

> `testssl.sh` raw stdout output

```
└─▪ bash testssl.sh --protocols --nodns none --sneaky --quiet --color 0 --wide --severity LOW --hints --json xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443

 Testing protocols via sockets except NPN+ALPN

 SSLv2      not offered (OK)
 SSLv3      server responded with higher version number (TLSv1.2) than requested by client (NOT ok)
 TLS 1      not offered -- server responded with higher version number (TLSv1.2) than requested by client
 TLS 1.1    offered (deprecated)
 TLS 1.2    offered (OK)
 TLS 1.3    not offered and downgraded to a weaker protocol
 NPN/SPDY   not offered
 ALPN/HTTP2 not offered
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is the server publicly accessible? Can you run https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ ? It seems your SSL/TLS server implementation has a bug and uses the wrong version in ServerHello. It's not necessarily a security issue. You should definitely disable support for SSLv3 because there is no way to use it securely. If you can, you should also disable support for TLS1.0 and TLS1.1, because the chance of an implementation that does not support TLS1.2 doing TLS1.0 securely is extremely small. It's best to only support in TLS1.2 the cipher suites allowed in TLS1.3, if you can.

Comment: @Z.T.: we don't know it's ServerHello, and I don't think I've even seen an implementation use wrong version in ServerHello, but I _have_ seen some send an alert to _reject_ the ClientHello and use wrong version for the _alert_. OP: you might add `-debug` to `openssl s_client` to get the exact protocol messages. Also for OpenSSL 1.0.1 be aware `s_client` by default doesn't send SNI, which most other TLS clients do, and according to the website testssl.sh 3.0 does. For some servers lack of SNI causes problems, though I wouldn't expect the one you have here.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Updated the output from the -debug flag. I've run the same scan on a machine with `testssl.sh` version `3.0.1` and OpenSSL version `1.1.1`, the result from `testssl.sh` doesn't change. @Z.T.: I've run the ssltest on SSL Labs it doesn't report this issue. I've also added raw output from the `testssh.sh`.

Comment: Your client did ClientHello (sslv3 with horribly insecure cipher suites and SCSV), the server answered some 81 bytes we don't see but with TLS1.2 record version, then the client sent alert fatal handshake_failure with version=TLS1.2, as soon as it saw the record layer version from the server, without reading the rest of the server's response (which was probably ServerHello). I don't think that's a security problem, though it is weird. Do disable SSLv3 on the server.